# Compile R package with clang in ubuntu

Tags: c++, c, r, makefile

Currently I am using ubuntu.

By default R uses g++ to compile c/c++ code in a R package.

How can I force R to use clang++/clang?

Comment: you can run configure script as `CC=clang++ ./configure ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2012-August/004208.html

> i)  clang -- and I do from time to time test with clang which works
> just fine
> "as is", ie on my Linux box I simply say this in `~/.R/Makevars`
>
> ```
> CXX=clang++
> CC=clang
> ```

Thanks Dirk!

Comment: There is an issue with clang in Ubuntu 13.10 though -- it doesn't set the include paths correctly. If you really need clang now, use the repo at llvm.org.

Answer (score 0):

I add more information to `Makevars` file to make it run finally.

```
CC=clang 
CXX=clang++
CXX98=clang++
CXX11=clang++
CXX14=clang++
CXX17=clang++
```